# Magento get current viewed product name on contact form.phtml on product page

Tags: magento-1.7, contact-form

Hello all i need to display product name on my contact from which is displayed on product page. So basically i want that my contact form will display currently viewing products name if anyone could help me doing so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are on the product view page you should be able to access the current product from the registry:

```
<?php $product = Mage::registry('product') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am trying to get the product name inside my contact form so i am able to get all collection of products through this $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection(); 
but what i need here is to get the viewed product from view.phtml so that i can get the details of that particular product inside my contact form. Thanks for your reply andrew please let me out of this thanks

Comment: I am not sure I follow you now. Have you included your contact form on your product view page yes?
If it's embedded inside your product view block/template then you can get the current product model as stated above...?

Comment: Thanks andrew for your help i get it through passing the id on get then i retrieved the id & make an object variable & load all the necessary details of product in it. Thank you very much for your help.